# Long commits and file changes from master on my feature branch after rebase

Tags: git, github

I rebased feature branch on master and the feature branch got a lot of commits and file changes. But file changes and other's commits on master shows and piles up on my feature branch because of being rebased and hard to get code reviewed from my co-worker.

My understanding of 'rebase' is that rebase command rewrites hole history and reapplies my commits on top of the history. And

- My feature branch has 4 files changes with 10 commits
- Master branch has 100 file changes with 20 commits

Now my feature branch has 104 files file changes with 30 commits.

**Not sure if I did it correctly in terms of workflow and if I did, is that normal that 100 file changes from `master` are shown on my feature branch and how people deal with it when your co-worker review your code?**

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide the tree of commits from both branches. It is not clear for me where did your changes diverge, and it is not clear what is the final problem. 30 commits on the rebased branch looks like en expected result. The rebased branch should have all the changes from both old-feature and master.

Answer (score 0):

The branch in git is just a "pointer" to a specific commit. Each commit knows it's parent, and this knowledge allows git to reconstruct the history for the branch starting from the last commit and up to the first commit in the repository. As a consiquence that means that after you create a new branch, there would be no info which branch is a parent and which one is the child.

So you had a `master` with 20 commits. Somewhere inside these 20 commits you created a new branch and made 10 additional commits on top of that. Now you wish to apply these 10 commits to the last commit on `master`: you would create a workflow of 20+10 commits. You branch would point to the last commit, and the whole branch would be 30 commits long.